# JS JQVMap hovercolor regions

Tags: javascript, mousehover, jqvmap

I'm new to JS and have no idea how to get this to work. I'm trying to color multiple regions if one of them is hovered by the mouse. I'm using a switch case to get all the regions together. And this seems to work so far, because I'm getting out my test line. I'm sure I'm just missing on a tiny thing here. I appreciate any help!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var red = '#E20079', blue = '#009EE0', yel = '#FFFA00';
    jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({
        map: 'usa_en',
        backgroundColor: '#383838',
        enableZoom: false,
        showTooltip: true,
        selectedColor: null,
        onRegionOver: function(event, code, region){             
            switch(code) {
                case 'wa': case 'or': case 'ca': case 'nv': case 'id':
                case 'mt': case 'wy': case 'ut': case 'az': case 'nm':
                case 'co': case 'ne': case 'ks': case 'sd': case 'nd':
                case 'mn': case 'wi': case 'ia': case 'il': case 'ak':
                case 'hi':
                    //this output is working fine
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = code;
                    //but it won't change the color!!
                    hoverColor: 'blue';
                    break;
                case 'mo': case 'ok': case 'tx': case 'ar': case 'la':
                case 'ms': case 'al': case 'ga': case 'fl': case 'tn':
                case 'ky': case 'sc': case 'in': case 'sc':
                    hoverColor: 'yel';
                    break;
                case 'mi': case 'oh': case 'nc': case 'va': case 'wv': 
                case 'pa': case 'de': case 'nj': case 'ny': case 'ct':
                case 'ri': case 'ma': case 'vt': case 'nh': case 'me':
                case 'md': case 'dc':
                    hoverColor: 'red';
                    break;
            }
        },
        onRegionClick: function(code){
            switch(code) {
                case 'wa': case 'or': case 'ca': case 'nv': case 'id':
                case 'mt': case 'wy': case 'ut': case 'az': case 'nm':
                case 'co': case 'ne': case 'ks': case 'sd': case 'nd':
                case 'mn': case 'wi': case 'ia': case 'il': case 'ak':
                case 'hi':
                    window.open("http://www.google.com");
                    break;
                case 'mo': case 'ok': case 'tx': case 'ar': case 'la':
                case 'ms': case 'al': case 'ga': case 'fl': case 'tn':
                case 'ky': case 'sc': case 'in': case 'sc':
                    window.open("http://www.yahoo.com");
                    break;
                case 'mi': case 'oh': case 'nc': case 'va': case 'wv': 
                case 'pa': case 'de': case 'nj': case 'ny': case 'ct':
                case 'ri': case 'ma': case 'vt': case 'nh': case 'me':
                case 'md': case 'dc':
                    window.open("http://www.example.com");
                    break;                  
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: could you please specify which js libraries you are using in the head?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored a bit your code to be less redundant, in some way.

My proposal is as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  // Group the codes of each state in the desired macro-areas
  var areas = [['wa','or','ca','nv','id','mt','wy','ut','az','nm','co','ne','ks','sd','nd','mn','wi','ia','il','ak','hi'],
               ['mo','ok','tx','ar','la','ms','al','ga','fl','tn','ky','sc','in'],
               ['mi','oh','nc','va','wv','pa','de','nj','ny','ct','ri','ma','vt','nh','me','md','dc']],
      // Assign links to areas
      links = {0: "http://www.google.com", 1: "http://www.yahoo.com", 2: "http://www.example.com"},
      // Define colors
      red = '#E20079', blue = '#009EE0', yel = '#FFFA00',
      // Assign colors to areas
      colors = {0: blue, 1: yel, 2: red},
      // Prepare container for hover colors
      hoverColors = {};
  (function () {
    // Build a ready-to-use hoverColors list
    areas.forEach(function(members, area) {
      members.forEach(function(state) {
        hoverColors[state] = colors[area];
      });
    });
  })();
  // Used in mouse enter and mouse leave handlers
  function toggleAreaHiglight(code, action){
    var vMap = $('#vmap');
    areas.forEach(function(members) {
      if(members.indexOf(code)>-1) {
        members.forEach(function(state) {
          if(state != code) vMap.vectorMap(action, state);
        });
      }
    });
  }
  // Initialize the map
  $('#vmap').vectorMap({
    map: 'usa_en',
    backgroundColor: '#383838',
    enableZoom: false,
    showTooltip: true,
    selectedColor: null,
    hoverColors: hoverColors,
    onRegionOver: function(event, code, region){
      toggleAreaHiglight(code, 'highlight');
    },
    onRegionOut: function(event, code, region){
      toggleAreaHiglight(code, 'unhighlight');
    },
    onRegionClick: function(event, code, region){
      var link = links[$(areas).map(function(i) {
        if(this.indexOf(code)>-1) return i;
      })[0]];
      if(link) window.open(link);
    }
  });
});
```

There are two parts which needs some explanation:

- **hoverColors**: i'm just preparing in advance an object which will
  contain the association between the code of a state and the needed
  hover color. The result then looks like this:

  ```
  {
    ak: "#009EE0",
    al: "#FFFA00",
    ar: "#FFFA00",
    ... all other states
    wv: "#E20079",
    wy: "#009EE0"
  }
  ```
- **toggleAreaHighlight**: why skipping the current region code in the toggle highlight function?

  ```
  if(state != code) $('#vmap').vectorMap(action, state);
  ```

  Highlighting and un-highlighting the current state (region) under the mouse pointer is already built-in, and and so, therefore, there is no need to handle it twice.

BTW, an additional note:

in your second area, you declared *South Carolina* two times, maybe this is a typo, but anyway, to avoid nasty unwanted side effects, each code **must** be just only once in the areas.

Comment: Hi deblocker, thanks for your replay and your work. I've replaced your code with mine and tryed to suss it out. But at the moment the map won't even show up. Maybe because of the libraries I'm using?
The libraries I'm using:
jquery-1.8.2.js, jquery-jvectormap.js, jquery-mousewheel.js, jvectormap.js

Comment: Hey deblocker, I've just noticed that I'm using other scipts in my postet example. I had a lot of try and error the past days, sry. For my example I'm using jquery-1.11.3.min.js, jquery.vmap.js.Thats just it. AND your work is realy nice, its working like intended.

Comment: THX for your feedback, that's fine .Yes, it is something that often happens to people, to be confused between jVestorMap and JQVMao. So at the end, i got it right that your example was using JQVMap. It yould be nice if you could adjust the tag below your  question to reflect that library. Have a nice day.